# Efficient storage of a text array column in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

My question is concerned primarily with database storage/space optimization. I have a table in my database that has
the following columns:

1. **id** : PRIMARY KEY INTEGER
2. **array_col** : UNIQUE TEXT[]

This table is - by far - the largest in the database (in terms of storage space) and contains about
~200 million records. The **array_col** has a few characteristics which make me suspicious that I
am not storing it in a very space optimal manner. They are as follows:

1. The majority of strings have a decent length to them (on average 25 characters)
2. The length of the text array is variable (typically 100+ strings per array)
3. The individual strings will repeat themselves with a decent frequency across records. On average
   a given string will appear in several thousand other records. (The array order tends to be similar
   across records too)

   | **id** | **array_col** |
   | --- | --- |
   | 1 | […,"20 torque clutch settings",…] |
   | 2 | […,"20 torque clutch settings",…] |
   | 3 | […,"20 torque clutch settings",…] |
   | … | … |

   The above table shows values repeating across records.

I do not want to normalize this table because treating the text array as an atomic unit is the most
useful for my application and it also makes querying much simpler. I also care about the ordering of
strings in the array as well.

I can think of two approaches to this problem:

1. **Create a lookup table** to avoid repeating strings. The assumption here is INT[] is probably
   more space efficient than a TEXT[].

   **Table 1**

   | **id** | **array_col** |
   | --- | --- |
   | 1 | […,47,…] |
   | 2 | […,47,…] |
   | 3 | […,47,…] |
   | … | … |

   **Table 2**

   | **id** | **name** |
   | --- | --- |
   | … | … |
   | 47 | "20 torque clutch settings" |
   | … | … |

   **Problem:** PostgreSQL, to my knowledge, does not support arrays of foreign keys. I'm also not sure what a trigger or stored procedure for this would look like. Database consistency would probably become more of a concern for me too.
2. **ZSON** ?, I have no experience in using this extension, but it sounds like it does something
   similar in terms of creating a lookup table of frequently used strings. To my understanding I would
   need to convert the array column to some kind of JSON string.

   ```json
   {"array_col":[…,“20 torque clutch settings”,…]}
   ```

   [GitHub - postgrespro/zson: ZSON is a PostgreSQL extension for transparent JSONB compression](https://github.com/postgrespro/zson)

Any advice on how to approach this problem would be greatly appreciated. Do any of the above choices
seem reasonable or a better long-term approach in terms of database design? I'm currently using
PostgreSQL 14 for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to optimize for storage space, tell PostgreSQL to compress the column whenever it exceeds 128 bytes:

```
ALTER TABLE tab SET (toast_tuple_target = 128);
```

Of course optimizing for space may not be good for performance.